# Modify an extension css in about:config of firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, tinymce

I am using the Zotero extension and I would like to change the way TinyMCE handle the space between paragraph. So I would like to customize the CSS by adding CSS rules to the extensions.zotero.note.css.

I would like to set this CSS rules because I find that the spacing about a new paragraph to wide:

```
p{ padding:0, margin:0}
```

So I enter `about:config` in the firefox URL address bar and I searched for extensions.zotero.note.css.

I can't figure out how I am supposed to add this new CSS rules:
- should I right-click and select modify and then add the CSS rules above?
- should I create a new string?
- What is the correct syntax for the string: should I entered `p` or `"p"` or ...?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right-click --> modify

Then paste the string into the pop-up window as you have it above, no quotation marks anywhere. 
Though I suspect it won't do what you want: to get rid of all paragraph spacing use something like

```
p {margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; padding-top 0}
```

Comment: Hey you are here too Adam! Thanks a lot for your help! That did the trick! Also I would like to add that I had to close Firefox for the change to be effective.